# How to fill out horizontal PDF forms using the PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How does one fill out a horizontal pdf form with the PDFBox library?

I access my fields and fill them using the supplied example code and it works fine. But, if the pdf page is tilted horizontally the filled out text are still left in the vertical position.

I have tried rotating the page first and then filling the form but the fields seem to be independent. I have also tried formatting the field through the various set methods defined for `PDField` and `PDTextbox` but this has no effect either.

Finally, I know that some of the rotation properties are controlled through the `PDAnnotation` and `PDAnnotationWidget` but trying to set their `PDAppearanceCharacteristics` has no effect on the initial text rotation. Rather, a user is required to interact with the field in order for this to take effect.

Thanking in advance,
J3lly